# Intercept event on changing font size

Tags: tinymce

When changing fontsize with tinymce it adds a span with attribute style set to eg. 'font-size: 12pt'.

I would like to intercept that behaviour and do something totally different. I would need the chosen value but I don't want the text to change in the text field only in my visualisation on another part of the page.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [`FormatApply`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/events/#editor-core-events) event to track if any format was applied.

Here is an example that will log every `FormatApply` event via the browser console:

```js
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('FormatApply', function(element) {
                console.log(element);
            });
        }
        
    });
```

I've also created a fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/t8iaab.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Any chance you have an idea on how to set this on the editor component in the Vue.js package? I don't see how I can set this in the attributes of this element...

Comment: Best way with the Vue component appears to be to set :init='variable' and then set the variable in you script. There you can use function statements.